# When does Pubnub Debug Console user Console_Admin unsubscribe/exit test channel?

Tags: pubnub

I am learning PubNub and building real time applications with PubNub

PubNub's new debug console allows me to connect several test clients to a channel of my choice - this is cool!

I notice that the debug console has a user named "Console_Admin" that subscribes to the channel. This user stays on the channel even when all test clients have unsubscribed and exited. This user appears to stay even when a new session is started with the Debug console.

I know this since I have another client running on my local machine that is listening to Presence events on the same channel. And the Console_Admin user has not left the channel, despite me having started a "New Session" on the Debug console

Does "Console_Admin" ever unsubscribe from the test channel? Is there a way I can have it unsubscribe?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that eventually the "Console_Admin" user does unsubscribe from the channel

After a while when I logged back on the channel from my local NodeJS client, the occupancy was down to 1 (indicating my local NodeJS client was the only one around)

The new PubNub Debug Console probably has some sort of 'lazy unsubscribe' for the Console_Admin users

Comment: good questions!  the original dev console will perform a full unsubscribe.  this allows the user `uuid` to be marked as "gone".  will need to review the process on the new Admin Debug Console.

Comment: @PubNub - thanks for confirming! I like the new Debug console btw- great stuff

Comment: awesome thank you!  I tested and looks like the new admin debug console will allow you to click an **`[ Unsubscribe ]`** button. This should send a "leave" event as expected.